# Custom Jackson mapper to handle mapping for an individual field?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I am using Jackson to serailize a Java model object into JSON, for one of the fields, lets say 'title', the way I map the value depends on another field's value. Therefore,it not a straight forward mapping.

Can I create a custom mapper that will be called when the 'title' field is mapped, allowing me to add the necessary logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example which customize output of Date field:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=CustomDateSerializer.class)
private Date timestamp;
```

CustomDateSerializer.class

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {  

    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider arg2) throws 
        IOException, JsonProcessingException {      

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy H:m:s");
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(value);
        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```